# Apply workflow to

Tags: verbs

i have a workflow called "X" that i will be using to do "Y". I was wondering what is the action verb that can be used before "workflow"?

Thanks.

Comment: A "workflow" is a series of tasks or a process.  Use the same verbs you would use with those terms.

Comment: Complete X to do Y.

Answer (score 1):

How about

> **Perform** the workflow.
>
> **Execute** the workflow.
>
> **Follow** the workflow.

Comment: The one I like least is 'perform' but I like them all enough to upvote your answer.

Answer (score 0):

**Process**

> to treat or prepare by some particular series of actions, as in manufacturing. ([Dictionary.com #10](http://www.dictionary.com/browse/process))